# Azure MSI token issue when applying ansible playbook from Azure CLI

Tags: azure, ansible, cloud, token, azure-managed-identity

I used to execute ansible playbook in Azure CLI cloud shell. All was perfectly fine for few years. Lats week i tried to execute simpleansible-playbbok  and face error as follow:

```
`fatal: \[localhost\]: FAILED! =\> {"changed": false, "msg": "Failed to get MSI token: 'MSIAuthentication' object has no attribute 'get_token'. Please check whether your machine enabled MSI or grant access to any subscription."}`
```

previously playbook was executing correctly and objects were created.

Playbook:

```
---
- name: Create Log Analytics Azure
  hosts: localhost
  connection: local
  gather_facts: false

  vars:
    resource_group_name: sandbox
    location: eastus
    workspace_name: loganalyticsforwaf

  tasks:
    - name: create Log Analytics workspace
      azure_rm_loganalyticsworkspace:
        resource_group: "{{ resource_group_name }}"
        name: "{{ workspace_name }}"
        location: "{{ location }}"
        sku: per_gb2018
```

I use buildin azure Cloud Shell with default ansible on board. I used to use it for past few years and all was OK. I checked that on few different account - all the same. Soemthing has changed...
Any idea how can I find source of the issue?

Thank you!

I tried to create Azure resource using Ansibla playbook.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: Opened an issue in Github - https://github.com/ansible-collections/azure/issues/1183

Tested and confirmed that the later version somehow broke the MSI workflow.  Tested this with `azure_rm_keyvaultsecret_info` as well, and got the same error.

The workaround is to revert back to `az.collection` version `1.13.0`.  Version greater or equal to 1.14.0 will get this error.

**NOTE**: Must also align the python packages with v1.13.0's requirements file. i.e.,
Once you revert the azcollection back to v1.13.0, you will need to install the associated python packages.

End-end-end instruction to revert to Azure Collection v1.13.0.

- Step 1: Install collection v1.13.0

  `ansible-galaxy collection install azure.azcollection:1.13.0`

  *Take note of the output, it should tell the path of the installed collection - which will be used for step 2.*
- Step 2: Install the required python packages for v1.13.0

  `pip install -r </path-to-azcollection>/requirements-azure.txt`

  *where `</path-to-azcollection>` is the obtained from the output of step 1*